# Run-time error '3075' VBA: Check if file already exists in table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I gave a piece of code where I am trying to check if a file has already been uploaded to a table. When files are uploaded the name of the file uploaded is put into a column called 'Name_of_report'. I am trying to run the below code and check if the file already exists in 'Table1' which holds all data.

However when I run the below code I get the error: Run-time error '3075': Syntax  error (missing operator) in query expression 'Name_of_report' = File1. xlsx (which is the value assigned to the TableName variable)

I know it's a simple fix but I'm very new to VBA and have tried various changes and can't seen to get it working.

An help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Check_TableExists(TableName As Variant)
If CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT count(Name_of_Report) FROM Table1 WHERE Name_of_Report =" & TableName & ";").Fields(0) > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Data already exists in table")
End If
```

Comment: Don't do these kind of checks. They are non-atomic, in other words, they consist of multiple steps, and has been is true a second ago (_"no record with this name exists"_) might not be true anymore when you try to insert the record step later. Instead... **Trust the database to prevent duplicates.** Create a unique key on the `Name_of_Report` column. Try to insert a new record with a regular `INSERT` statement. If this fails with a "duplicate key" error, the data already exists. Catch the error and show a message to the user. (Use `On Error Resume Next` and `If Err.Number = ...  Then`)

Comment: As name of report is for sure a string, you should check how strings are queried. Store sql statement in a variable and output it with`Debug.Print`then paste code to new query (sql-view). That reveals lots of wrong sql statements.

Comment: Not to forget, after statement works try to store a name that contains your literal delimiter, then read [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/msaccess)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters for text type field need apostrophe delimiters.

`If CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT count(Name_of_Report) FROM Table1 WHERE Name_of_Report ='" & TableName & "';").Fields(0) > 0 Then`

However, domain aggregate function could accomplish instead of opening recordset.

`If DCount("*", "Table1", "Name_of_Report='" & TableName & "'") > 0 Then`